# If the css is only on one page in razor pages should I still write in in wwwroot or have it only on the page?

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

If the css is only on one page in razor pages should I still write in in wwwroot or have it only on the page? What is best approach with minimal size?

I'm learning about Razor pages and thinking about the correct way of doing things. What is the right way?

Comment: Which .Net Version are you using now? From .net 6, There is a new feature called CSS Isolation, You can refer to this [link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages) to learn more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From .Net 6, There is a new feature called CSS Isolation for Razor Page/view.

CSS isolation means creating a CSS file like `.cshtml.css` for each razor page/view(.cshtml). CSS isolation helps to avoid dependencies on global styles that will be very hard to maintain and also avoid style conflicts among the nested content.

In this isolation process, the style defined in the `.csthm.css` file are scoped and they are applied to respective razor pages/views. For example, any styling that is added in `index.cshtml.css` file will only apply to `index.cshtml` page, they won't affect any other page in the application.

The .NET framework runtime will bundle all the isolated CSS files(*.csthml.css) in the single file that is `{your_application_name}.styles.css`. So this bundled CSS line will be added automatically at `{Pages/Views}/Shared/_Layout.cshml` by the framework.

The bundle CSS file({your_application}.styles.css) can maintain styles of each file without any conflict with the help of applying scope identifier like `b-{10_character_string}`. So the scoped identifier `b-{10_character_string}` will be unique for each file.

More information you can refer [link1](https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/razor-pages-css-isolation-3f5),[link2](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/11/dotnet6-css-isolation-razor-pages-or-views.html).

Comment: I'm using .net 7. So what css should be on the page in css isolation and what css should be in wwwroot?

Comment: There is no rule that you must put specified css file into specified folder, It's depend on your style, In my opinion, I will put some generic css file into wwwroot. You can put the whole css  into css isolation or only the part

Comment: Ok, thank you! And what about js, is there anything similar? And how you can use function from wwwroot in your page? For example on onlick event or ajax?

Comment: In my opinion, If my js code is not too long, I will write it in the page directly, But if js code is too long or it is a generic js code, I will create a individual js file in wwwroot.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And what about "And how you can use function from wwwroot in your page? For example on onlick event or ajax?"

Comment: CSS Isolation doesn't address the OPs question because the combined file is included in every page on the site

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about minimising size and HTTP requests, you can use a section to output the CSS styles for a specific page:

```
@section css{
    <style>
    .local-style{color:blue;}
    </style>
}
```

Then in your layout:

```
<head>
    ...
    @RenderSection("css", required:false)
</head>
```

That way, the css will only be rendered for the specific page. Note that CSS isolation, which has also been mentioned, bundles all isolated styles into one file which is included in every page, so you gain nothing over just adding your page-specific styles to a *site.css* file.